# Is it possible to include my one page Eloqua microsite in a subdirectory rather than as a subdomain

Tags: eloqua

I have an Eloqua microsite that I would like to integrate into my main website as smoothly as possible.  The site is a single page, and I am am hoping to include it as a subdirectory rather than a subdomain e.g. www.mydomain/microsite.

Is it possible to do this with an Eloqua microsite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently Eloqua only works with subdomains, not subfolders.